# Set ViewController Title from calloutAccessoryControlTapped

Tags: ios, objective-c, mkmapview, mapkit, mkannotation

I am trying to simply set the title of a detailViewController to the title of a pin once the call out accessory control is tapped.

**Here is where I set the MKAnnotation up:**

```
- (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id 
<MKAnnotation>)annotation
{
MKAnnotationView *annotationView = [[MKPinAnnotationView alloc] 
initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"loc"];
```

**Here is where I want to set the title of the detail view controller to the pin title:**

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view     
calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{

DetailViewController *controller = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil
                                                                            bundle:nil];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES]; // or use     
presentViewController if you're using modals

controller.title = pin.annotationView.subtitle;

}
```

The last line is what is messed up. Any ideas? Thank you all!!

Answer (score 2):

Figured it out - replaced the controller title with:

```
controller.title = view.annotation.title;
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView annotationView:(MKAnnotationView *)view     
calloutAccessoryControlTapped:(UIControl *)control
{
MKAnnotation * annotation = (MKAnnotation *)annotation;

DetailViewController *controller = [[DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil
                                                                            bundle:nil];
controller.title = annotation.subtitle;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES]; // or use     
presentViewController if you're using modals

}
```

The above code works fine for me Mr.Brandon